# Installation of Kerberos5-1.12.1

Tags: kerberos

While installing Kerberos I'm facing an error at making a file by running the following command:

make

This is the error I'm facing:

```
yacc getdate.y

make[2]: yacc: Command not found

make[2]: *** [getdate.c] Error 127

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kevin/Documents/krb5-1.12.1/src/kadmin/cli'

make[1]: *** [all-recurse] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kevin/Documents/krb5-1.12.1/src/kadmin'

make: *** [all-recurse] Error 1
```

Please help me how to deal with it...

Comment: have you got yacc installed?

Comment: You need to install yacc through your package manager. I have compiled MIT Kerberos 1.12.1 very successfully on RHEL 6 and HP-UX 11.31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rowland Shaw and Michael-O in the comments, I got it working with the instructions here: [how to install Lex and Yacc in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871425/how-to-install-lex-and-yacc-in-ubuntu)

The problem is that yacc isn't installed. Install yacc (with apt-get it's `sudo apt-get install byacc flex`) and it should work.