# Mulval: installation problems

Tags: java, installation

when I try to install mulval I get the following error:

```
(cd src/adapter; make; make install)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/src/adapter'
javac GetCVEID.java -cp :/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar
make[1]: javac: Comando não encontrado
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'GetCVEID.class' failed
make[1]: *** [GetCVEID.class] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/src/adapter'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/src/adapter'
javac GetCVEID.java -cp :/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar
make[1]: javac: Comando não encontrado
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'GetCVEID.class' failed
make[1]: *** [GetCVEID.class] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/src/adapter'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'adapter' failed
make: *** [adapter] Error 2
```

And I already have MULVALROOT set according to this tutorial: http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~xou/argus/software/mulval/readme.html

My PATH:

```
/home/rvmelo/mulval/XSB/bin:/home/rvmelo/mulval/XSB/utils:/usr/local/sbin:/
usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/
snap/bin:/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/bin:/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval/utils:/
home/rvmelo/mulval/XSB/bin
```

MULVALROOT:

```
/home/rvmelo/mulval/mulval
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed a JRE and you need to compile Java classes (need javac which is included in the JDK). These are the [differences between JRE and JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906455/520275)

From your logs:

```
 make[1]: javac: Comando não encontrado
```

Just [install a JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html).

Comment: thank you! it worked but now I get this error: make[1]: lex: Comando não encontrado Makefile:7: recipe for target 'lex.yy.c' failed

Comment: Install lex -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871425/how-to-install-lex-and-yacc-in-ubuntu#3871441

Comment: Thank you! know it worked! so I had to download jre, sdk, lex, and than bison in order to work